# Php showing html tags in browser

Tags: php, html, tags, centos

PHP is not encoding html tags and instead of this its simply printing html tags in the browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>

<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<link href="https://sds.com//sdsd/index.php?storename=all&insertedid=100&references=externalsite&fbrefresh=20140820083315" rel="canonical" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="34324324324234324">

<meta property="og:site_name" content=""/>
<meta property="og:title" content="" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="Number of Links: " /> 
<meta property="og:url" content="https://sss.com/ge/index.php?storename=all&insertedid=100&references=externalsite&fbrefresh=2`enter code here`0140820083315">
<meta property="og:type" content="sdsdsdsd:picture" />
<meta property="og:image" content="">
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Or, is it just me? Edit: Nope, it's not just me.

Comment: Me neither @Fred-ii- could you expand on the question arjun

Comment: PHP code is not shown in browser.

Comment: Its a php page which contain HTML tags. Instead of the graphical view, the source code is getting printed in the browser.

Comment: @arjunarjun Are you encoding your HTML tags in php

Comment: @arjunarjun can you post just a small part of PHP

Comment: Ashesh Kumar - My php code not even printing any html codes. Its ignoring html codes  and its printing the raw html code in browser. Whether i need to change anything in the server.

Comment: Can you check if a php-page with just the following content is shown ok? <?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: Dave G - Its showing only the html codes in browser.

Comment: @arjunarjun Which Browser? and please post one line of php

Comment: please check the screenshot here [link] http://i.imgur.com/LtZmIIC.png

Comment: PHP is not encoding html tags and instead of this its simply printing html tags in the browser.

Comment: @arjunarjun are you using <?php and ?>

Comment: @arjunarjun Post a screenshot of your PHP code in your code editor

Comment: You have `<title>phpinfo()</title>` you need to do `<title><?php phpinfo(); ?></title>` if anything.

Answer (score 0):

Since the HTML looks ok to me, I think it is not a PHP problem, but a problem of the server / browser configuration - the browser shows the HTML as text instead of interpreting it. @Arjun: What webserver do you use? What is the name of the PHP file (ending with .php)? Which browser do you use?

Comment: Hi,I am using centos machine with apache php 5.3. I am testing this in firefox latest version.

Comment: Ok, then I think it's caused by the filename; if I open a file named *.html in my FireFox, everything is ok, if I open a file named *.txt, FireFox show the HTML as text.